# Is there any multi-touch standalone monitor available for regular desktop PC use that supports windows 8 multitouch?

Tags: windows-8, display

I know that there are several generations of touch-screen technology out there. There is the ancient resistive touch, pre win7 era capacitive, pre win7 era multitouch capacitive, and win7 compliant multitouch capacitive.    However Win8 requires yet another new generation of hardware.  I have been unable to find any Windows 8 compatible multi-touch capacitive monitors that will work with a regular desktop PC.  The use (primary application) would be for development and test of multi-touch windows applications.

I'm not asking if any all-in-one PCs that support windows 8 multi-touch exist, for those are a different class of device, nor devices like Surface. I want to know if there is such a thing as a monitor that is standalone that will run with a regular developer mini-tower PC, that supports multi-touch in windows 8.

Comment: I was looking for one myself. It seems Windows 8 was designed for *no bezel* on the monitor. If your finger can't easily slide completely off the screen, some gestures are difficult or even impossible.

Comment: Sample Win7-monitor that's close, but no Win8 support. http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14367_div/14367_div.PDF

Comment: I would like to convert to community wiki but don't see how to do it here.

Comment: @WarrenP I saw your flag requesting CW, but it looks like this question is off-topic in the first place. [Shopping recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are not allowed, as per our [FAQ].

Comment: As per that link, asking the question as a technical question, not as a "which one should I buy?" is ON topic as per the faq.  This is a technical questiona bout the availability of multi-touch. So far, the answer is there are zero shipping multitouch Win8 monitors. I think that's a major, important fair PC hardware question.  Otherwise, all questions comparing hardware, or asking of certain hardware exists would be "shopping", which seems far too broad.

Answer (score 3):

23" [Acer T232HL](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.VT2AA.001)

27" [Acer T272HL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00966IW6I) (Not shipping/or on Acer site yet)

27" [Planar PCT2785](http://www.planartouch.com/products/pct2785/) (Will ship after December 6th, 2012)

Comment: Will add more as I find them.

Comment: Maybe this should be CW'd?

Comment: how do I do that? I don't see any button to make it a community wiki.   I found one finally (two actually), from Acer.   h0twir3 please add this one: http://www.neowin.net/news/two-new-windows-8-certified-touchscreen-monitors-from-acer